# AngularJS Table from array

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs, datatable

I'm developing a project in AngularJS and I need some help.
I have a table in my index that receives the data from an array that contains the reading of a CSV file.
The first example works, but I would like to have a table structure as shown in second example. 
Can someone help me to adapt this for the second example? thanks
(i have tried so many times but without success)

First example (that works):

```
<table class="table table-sm table-dark table-bordered" id="myTable">
    <tr  ng-repeat="x in data track by $index">
      <td id="barraca" ng-repeat="y in x track by $index">{{ y }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Second example (that i want):

```
<table id="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Just copy over the ng-repeat code to the 2nd table row and td.

Comment: @tbone849 thank you for the help but can you be more explicit? I'm a little lost with the ng-repeat output...

Comment: @HelderSantos can you post a sample of the input data?

Comment: @CrhistianRamirez 
is an array structured by lines: [["Notas","NAlunos"],["5","2"],["10","7"],["15","8"],["20","1"]]. First line the header and others the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull out the first row from the input data to use as headers and the other rows should look pretty similar to your first example.

```js
angular.module('application', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    const csvData = [
      ["Notas", "NAlunos"],
      ["5", "2"],
      ["10", "7"],
      ["15", "8"],
      ["20", "1"]
    ];
    $scope.headers = csvData[0]; // just first row
    $scope.rows = csvData.splice(1); // all rows except first
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="application" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <table id="table_id">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="header in headers">{{header}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <td ng-repeat="data in row">{{data}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```